# Per Second statistics in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a file which contains Timestamps like this:

```
0.000100
0.003890
0.567980
0.999000
0.999990
1.000010
1.236800
1.456098
1.989001
2.098710
2.309879
2.890879
```

I want to find the per-second statistics , like in 1st second: 5 values, 2nd second: 4, 3rd second 3 in the file above using R. I also want to find Avg per second, max value in all the seconds and minimum value in all seconds. How can these be extracted using R? I am a newbie to R and still learning. I know how to plot these in histograms, but don't know how to extract the values.

Data:

```
x <- c(0.0001, 0.00389, 0.56798, 0.999, 0.99999, 1.00001, 1.2368, 1.456098, 
    1.989001, 2.09871, 2.309879, 2.890879)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the cut function to create a factor (time range) and then use in a similar fashion to how Justin proposes with aggregate:

```
y <- data.frame(val=x, time=cut(x, 0:round(max(x))))
aggregate(val~time, y, length)
aggregate(val~time, y, mean)
```

Or create your own function and do it in one fell swoop:

```
funner <- function(x){
    c(mean=mean(x), n=length(x), min=min(x), max=max(x), sd=sd(x))
}

aggregate(val~time, y, funner)
```

yielding:

```
> aggregate(val~time, y, funner)
   time  val.mean     val.n   val.min   val.max    val.sd
1 (0,1] 0.5141920 5.0000000 0.0001000 0.9999900 0.4996575
2 (1,2] 1.4204773 4.0000000 1.0000100 1.9890010 0.4223025
3 (2,3] 2.4331560 3.0000000 2.0987100 2.8908790 0.4102205
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using integer math:

```
x <- c(1e-04, 0.00389, 0.56798, 0.999, 0.99999, 1.00001, 1.2368, 1.456098, 
1.989001, 2.09871, 2.309879, 2.890879)

> aggregate(x, list(x %/% 1), mean)
  Group.1        x
1       0 0.514192
2       1 1.420477
3       2 2.433156
>
```

I would also suggest you look `data.table` and `plyr` packages for this sort of aggregation.

The `max` and `min` for each group follow fairly easily.  If you just want the `max` or `min` of the series you can use those functions directly

```
> max(x)
[1] 2.890879
>
```

Comment: Grouping by `trunc(x)` might even be faster. Perhaps : `tapply(x, trunc(x), mean)` and to get the lengths should they be needed: `tapply(x, trunc(x), length)`

Comment: @Dwin good point, `trunc` or `floor` is probably faster than the "math" approach.

Comment: @DWin and Just both very nice responses that are faster than my own.  It always amazes me how creative people are with vectorized solutions. +1 (DWin may I suggest you add your solution?)